# i am unable to see the login page on the web browser

Tags: html, servlets, web.xml

this is the java code:i am not getting any error indication but the output of the code is not displayed on the web server.it is showing the web address as:(http://localhost:6027/HttpSearchBar/Example). Tell me whether the local host 6027 is a valid address?

```
package search.com;

import java.io.IO Exception;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class Example extends HttpServlet{
 /**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 102831973239L;

public void dopost (HttpServletRequest hreq, HttpServletResponse hres)throws ServletException, IOException{
    System.out.println("hello");

    try {
        hres.setContentType("text/html");
        String s1 = hreq.getParameter("username");
        String s2 = hreq.getParameter("password");
        ServletContext sc = getServletContext();

        if ((s1.equals("abc"))&&(s2.equals("xyz"))) {
            hres.sendRedirect("welcome");

        }else {
            PrintWriter pw = hres.getWriter();
            pw.print("invalid username/password");
            RequestDispatcher rd = sc.getRequestDispatcher("login.html");
            rd.include(hreq, hres);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        System.err.print(e);
    }
} }
```

this is html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Example Html</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor=yellow text=blue>
<center>
    <h1>
        <u>LoginForm</u>
    </h1>
    <form action="Example" method="post">
        UserName<input type="text" name="username"> 
        Password<input type="text" name="Password"> 
        <input type="submit" value="login" /><input type="reset">


    </form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

this is web.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>HttpSearchBar</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Example</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Example</servlet-class>

  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Example</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Example</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/Example</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/Example</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.servlet.ServletException</exception-type>
    <location>/Example</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <exception-type>java.io.IOException</exception-type>
    <location>/Example</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang. Throw able </exception-type>
    <location>/search.com.Example</location>
  </error-page>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>login.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>login.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

this is displayed when server is started:

```
Oct 22, 2018 6:41:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher 
invoke
WARNING: Servlet Example is currently unavailable
```

Answer (score 1):

Send a request to `http://localhost:6027/` from your browser. If you can see the default Apache Tomcat [page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TqxW.png) the localhost:6027 is a valid address.

---

There are a couple of reasons that you might not see any response.

1. Java is case sensitive. Your do post method is incorrect. Replace with `doPost`

   ```
   public void doPost(HttpServletRequest hreq, HttpServletResponse hres)
       throws ServletException, IOException {
   ```
2. Your html password input name is `name="Password"`, and you are getting it with lowercase `p`.

   ```
   String s2 = hreq.getParameter("Password"); //uppercase P
   ```
3. Finally don't use `RequestDispatcher`, just redirect the page. Replace everything in your `else` statement.

   ```
   hres.sendRedirect("login.html");
   ```

Answer (score 0):

By referring to the server log that has attached, it seems that you are trying to run your servlet project on apache tomcat server. Default Tomcat port is 8080. That is you should try to access your running app on:
    http://localhost:8080

if you want to customize the running port you have to do it using the **server.xml** file.

Comment: thank you for the reply, i can see only the plain page  on the server, the buttons of username,password, login are not appearing in the web page after running the Servlet. It is showing a warning of Servet is currently  unavailable. help me mainly on this trouble.

Comment: the way you can guarantee that your server is running is just try to access http://localhost:[port] from your browser. It should render the server home page